# How to record audio & video of user in skype real time media calling?

Tags: botframework, skype-bots

I want to ask questions to the user and record his response, like a IVR bot but I want to record both audio and video of the user. Is it possible to do that with real time media calling?

I had gone through the [samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-RealTimeMediaCalling), but I did not understand on how to specify when to record the audio/video.

Comment: Are you planning on using Node.js or C# SDK?

Comment: C#. I had implemented a IVR bot but real time media calling has totally a different structure :/

Comment: You can use the realtime media calling API to record a user’s audio and video. This is not possible with the IVR version.

Answer (score -1):

IVR bots are audio-only, they do not support video. Video is supported with a real-time media bot.

A real-time media bot can record the audio and video streams (and, ideally, notify the Skype caller that it may be recording the call). We do not provide a full sample showing this scenario. There is an answer for similar question on the [GitHub site](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-RealTimeMediaCalling/issues/25):

> In a 1:1 Skype video call with your real-time media bot, the bot has
>   access to the Skype caller's audio and video. The Huebot sample shows
>   a bot receiving the audio and video of the Skype caller. To create a
>   recording, the bot could save the contents of audio and video media
>   buffers to disk and use a tool like ffmpeg to process them into an MP4
>   file, for example. But there's no specific recording sample. Also note
>   that the bot cannot control what resolution it receives of the Skype
>   caller's video, and will likely get a low resolution such as 240p.

Hope this help!!

Comment: As you can see in https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-RealTimeMediaCalling/issues/25#issuecomment-373621176 I am the same person who commented on Github. I am looking for a sample I can refer to develop an IVR type bot that can record the user video.

Comment: Sorry Anita... I followed up with the Skype team and this is the only information which I received. Will update with the sample I reproduce it.